# how can i connect to ethereum p2p network without node?

Tags: ether, nodes, network, rust

Is it possible to connect to an Ethereum P2P network without running a node, and if so, how can one accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to connect to Ethereum network?

Comment: And what do you want to do? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. There are a lot of node providers that give you free API keys for interaction with the blockchain.(e.g. Alchemy, Ankr). You can use node providers to send your transactions to be verified by the nodes and included in the blockchain or to read data from the blockchain.